# using multiple parameters in get method from (axios) reactjs front-end to asp.net core webapi Back-end

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios, webapi

I want to get shop by userId and userName if the shop for that user exists.
i have used the  url in axios get call as follows:

```
const url = `${config.apiUrl}/api/Shops/`
useEffect(() => {
    
    axios.get(url + `details?id=${user.id}&shopuser=${user.username}`)
    .then((res) => {
      setShop(res.data);
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    }

    )
```

At the back-end asp.net core web api I have used the following action Method:

```
 [HttpGet("{dashboard}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Shop>> Dashboard(int id,string shopuser)
        {
           
    var shop = await _context.Shops.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a=>a.UserId==id && a.UserName==shopuser);


            if (shop == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return shop;
        }
```

The problem is that the call is not sent to this action method with correct parameters and hence the response with error `error 500` .

The controller name is as follows:

```
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ShopsController : ControllerBase
    {
     .......
      ....
     }
   }
```

I have checked the `Network tab of console` the parameters are sent as follows:

```
/api/Shops/details?id=1&shopuser=asifranjha
```

thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[HttpGet("{dashboard}")]** annotation means that your get request is expecting a **route parameter** (dashboard).
So if you want to trigger your method, you should call **/api/Shops/1?shopuser=asifranjha**
 (I recommend you to keep the same naming so you should change *dashboard* to *id* or the opposite, you could also provide the type for your route with [route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints)).

If you want to use **/api/Shops/details?id=1&shopuser=asifranjha**, you should just change your annotation parameter so it would look like this: **[HttpGet("details")]**  and everything should work.
Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi @Valentin Richet  , thank you for solving my problem and explaining the difference.